# How can I control a Yale deadbolt with Google Home?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant, smart-lock

I've got a Yale Assure Lock SL with Z-Wave that I'd like to control with my new Google Home. I understand that the "unlock" command might be disabled for security reasons, but I'd at least like to be able to lock and check the locked/unlocked state with my voice.

I can control the lock with my SmartThings app on my Android phone just fine, and the other devices controlled by my SmartThings Hub show up correctly in Google Home so I know the two devices are talking, but in Google Home when I click on the plus to add a device, the lock doesn't show up. It does say that some locks require setting up in Google Nest, which I downloaded and installed, but I can't find anywhere in there to add a device.

I've read online that one solution is to create a "virtual switch" but the Google Home app on my Android phone doesn't appear to have that option.

How can I get Google Home to "see" my deadbolt?

EDIT

I followed [this question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/838/how-can-i-securely-support-unlocking-my-door-through-google-home?rq=1) to [this page](https://community.smartthings.com/t/google-home-door-locks/62423/10), which definitely seems like it's answering my question.  Back in January of 2018, OldSchool4664 Lance posted these instructions:

- Create a routine to unlock the door
- On https://graph.api.smartthings.com under “My Devices” click “New Device” and create a “Momentary button tile” called “Unlock the front door button”
- Edit your routine to be triggered by the tile
- At this point you can unlock the door by saying “Ok Google, turn on unlock the front door button”
- Go to https://ifttt.com/my_applets and create a new applet. For “if this” link to the Google Assistant service and select “Say a simple phrase”. I recommend you use a code phrase, for example “open sesame”, so someone can’t unlock your door by yelling from outside
- For “then that” select the SmartThings service and have it activate the “Unlock the front door button” tile

But it's not working for me.

Everything I can find talks about using the SmartThings Classic app (apparently Samsung didn't include all the functionality in their newer app) but when I download & install that, and follow the instructions [here](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/troubleshooting/TSG01109768/#add-a-routine-to-lock-the-front-door-with-smartthings-classic), the promised "Add a Routine" is nowhere to be seen.  And in the newer SmartThings app, there's absolutely nothing I can find about routines.  There are automations which seem similar, but I can't get them to work.

Comment: It [looks like](https://community.smartthings.com/t/classic-app-removed-routines/178334) you may need to get [an APK for an older version of the app.](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/smartthings/smartthings-smartthings)

Comment: In the Google Home app I can see 'Yale Access', 'Yale Smart Living' and 'Yale View'. Which of these 3 are you selecting when adding the device to Google Home?

Comment: None of those ... from the Home app, I click on the "plus" in the top-left corner, and select Set up device.  I then have to choose between "Set up new devices in your home" or "have something already set up".  Under "have something already setup" I see the 3 options you list, but clicking on any of them takes me to a "log into Yale" screen, and I don't have a Yale account.